# Can I make specifying one property require another be set, too?

Tags: typescript

Here's an example. Assume I don't control the data format.

```
type Thing = {
  name: string
}

// if you canJump, you need to specify howHigh
type Jump = {
  canJump: true
  howHigh: number
}

// MightJump Things either jump or don't 
type MightJump = Thing | (Thing & Jump)

const thing: MightJump = {
  name: 'hi',
  canJump: true,
  // howHigh: 5, // how do I make commenting this out an error?
}
```

So, ideally, for values with type `MightJump`, if only `name` is set, that's fine, but if either `canJump` or `howHigh` is set, the other in that pair is also required.

Is this possible in TypeScript? If not, what manner of change to the compiler would be required to support it? I'm very interested in the exact nature of the limitation.

From what I can tell, `Thing | (Thing & Jump)` results in a type where both `canJump` and `howHigh` are just optional, and only `name` remains required.

Update: Using artem's answer below:

```
type OptNever<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: never
}

type AllOrNone<T> = T | OptNever<T>

type MightJump = Thing & AllOrNone<Jump>
```

Comment: Have you tried interfaces?

Comment: Yes - it doesn't affect the outcome

Comment: ok I got what you are trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disallow the presence of a property in a member of a union type by giving it an optional `never` type:

```
type Thing = {
  name: string
}

// if you canJump, you need to specify howHigh, and vice versa
type JumpOrNot = { canJump?: never; howHigh?: never} | {
  canJump: true
  howHigh: number
}

// MightJump Things either jump or don't 
type MightJump = Thing & JumpOrNot

const thing: MightJump = {
  name: 'hi',
  canJump: true,
  // error
  // Type '{ name: string; canJump: true; }' is not assignable to type 'MightJump'.
  //    Type '{ name: string; canJump: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Thing & { canJump: true; howHigh: number; }'.
  //      Type '{ name: string; canJump: true; }' is not assignable to type '{ canJump: true; howHigh: number; }'.
  //        Property 'howHigh' is missing in type '{ name: string; canJump: true; }'.
}

const thing1: MightJump = {
  name: 'thing1'
}

const thing2: MightJump = {
  name: 'thing2',
  canJump: true,
  howHigh: 5, 
}
```

Comment: Made this easier with

    ```export type OptNever<T> = {
        [K in keyof T]?: never
    };

    export type AllOrNone<T> = T | OptNever<T>;

    type MightJump = Thing & AllOrNone<Jump>```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the types of the union are incompatible

```
type Thing = {
  name: string
}

// if you canJump, you need to specify howHigh
type Jump = {
  canJump: true
  howHigh: number
}

// MightJump Things either jump or don't 
type MightJump = (Thing & { canJump?: false } )| (Thing & Jump)

const thing: MightJump = {
  name: 'hi',
  canJump: true,
  // howHigh: 5, // error
}
```

This is a bit of quirky behavior in how checking for extra proepries works for unions. Normally if you assign an object literal with extra properties the compiler would complain, but if the properties belong to any type of the union it will not. So your literal is assignable to`Thing` just with some extra properties. If we make it explicitly incompatible with`Thing` we get an error.

Comment: That only fixes the issue for `howHigh` but it happens the same with `canJump`

Comment: @J.Pichardo Not sure what you mean. If you leave out`howHigh` when specifing `canJump:true` you get an error. That was my understanding of the question.

Comment: Yeah but OP wants to enforce the existence of both or none, either `canJump & howHigh` or none

Comment: @J.Pichardo it can also work with `type MightJump = (Thing & { canJump?: undefined } )| (Thing & Jump)` and then `canJump` can be true or false, and must be specified with `howHigh`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to have a negating type, something like:

```
type CantJump = {
   canJump?: undefined
   howHigh?: undefined
}
```

And then your `MightJump` type would be

```
type MightJump = Thing & ( Jump | CantJump )
```

That way you are enforcing both properties or none.

There is currently a [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7993) for an `unlike` keyword which would possibly allow something like:

```
type MightJump = Thing & ( Jump | unlike Jump )
```

However, is waiting for more feedback, meaning that there hasn't been enough support for it.